# How i can use image in navigation bar title in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

i'm in trouble. i want to use image in navigation bar title, but i'm getting a error i.e "UIImage" is not a subtype of "NSString". Below the code, look it.

```
class Dashboard: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = UIImage(named: "logo.png")        
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Anyone can suggest? Thanks!

Comment: You can't assign an object of type UIImage to a NSString. The navigationItem's title can only hold textual data (NSString).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the navigationItem's titleView

```
var image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

Answer (score 1):

worked for me

```
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "headerLogo")
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+, iOS 13+

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "id_logo"))
```