# iOS - add image and text in title of Navigation bar

Tags: swift, navigationbar

I would like to create a nav bar similar to what's in the image that's attached.

The title of the nav bar will be a combination of an image and text.

1. Should this be done per any best practice?
2. How can it be done?

[image: Screen shot of mockup of nav bar with image and text]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26690954/2274694), the easiest solution is to add the text to your image and add that image to the navigation bar like so:

```
var image = UIImage(named: "logo.png")
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

But if you have to add text and an image separately (for example, in the case of localization), you can set your navigation bar's title view to contain both image and text by adding them to a `UIView` and setting the `navigationItem`'s title view to that `UIView`, for example (assuming the navigation bar is part of a navigation controller):

```
// Only execute the code if there's a navigation controller 
if self.navigationController == nil {
    return
}

// Create a navView to add to the navigation bar
let navView = UIView()

// Create the label
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Text"
label.sizeToFit()
label.center = navView.center
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

// Create the image view
let image = UIImageView()
image.image = UIImage(named: "Image.png")
// To maintain the image's aspect ratio:
let imageAspect = image.image!.size.width/image.image!.size.height
// Setting the image frame so that it's immediately before the text:
image.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x-label.frame.size.height*imageAspect, y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.size.height*imageAspect, height: label.frame.size.height)
image.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

// Add both the label and image view to the navView
navView.addSubview(label)
navView.addSubview(image)

// Set the navigation bar's navigation item's titleView to the navView
self.navigationItem.titleView = navView

// Set the navView's frame to fit within the titleView
navView.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: @NaveedAhmad. Thanks lady, not Man. :)

Answer (score 19):

Use horizontal `UIStackView` should be much cleaner and easier

Please add the next extension to `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setTitle(_ title: String, andImage image: UIImage) {
        let titleLbl = UILabel()
        titleLbl.text = title
        titleLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let titleView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, titleLbl])
        titleView.axis = .horizontal
        titleView.spacing = 10.0
        navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    }
}
```

then use it inside your viewController:

```
setTitle("yourTitle", andImage: UIImage(named: "yourImage"))
```

(this will align the text and the icon together to the center, if you want the text to be centered and the icon in the left, just add an empty `UIView` with width constraint equal to the icon width)

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz can you provide more details please?

Comment: I copy pasted your code and run it. But title was not showing. I am writing this code in root view controller of my navigation controller.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot. For some people, the title might not show because the textColor is white.

Comment: Great and "swifty" solution, and also very simple. Thanks!

Comment: more elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

here is my 2 cents for Swift 4, since accepted answer didn't work for me (was mostly off the screen):

```
// .. in ViewController
var navBar = CustomTitleView()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    // =================== navBar =====================
    navBar.loadWith(title: "Budget Overview", leftImage: Images.pie_chart)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navBar

}

class CustomTitleView: UIView
{

var title_label = CustomLabel()
var left_imageView = UIImageView()

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup(){
    self.addSubview(title_label)
    self.addSubview(left_imageView)

}

func loadWith(title: String, leftImage: UIImage?)
{

    //self.backgroundColor = .yellow

    // =================== title_label ==================
    //title_label.backgroundColor = .blue
    title_label.text = title
    title_label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: FontManager.fontSize + 5)


    // =================== imageView ===================
    left_imageView.image = leftImage

    setupFrames()
}

func setupFrames()
{

    let height: CGFloat = Navigation.topViewController()?.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 44
    let image_size: CGFloat = height * 0.8

    left_imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: (height - image_size) / 2,
                                  width: (left_imageView.image == nil) ? 0 : image_size,
                                  height: image_size)

    let titleWidth: CGFloat = title_label.intrinsicContentSize.width + 10
    title_label.frame = CGRect(x: left_imageView.frame.maxX + 5,
                               y: 0,
                               width: titleWidth,
                               height: height)



    contentWidth = Int(left_imageView.frame.width)
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(contentWidth), height: height)
}


var contentWidth: Int = 0 //if its CGFloat, it infinitely calls layoutSubviews(), changing franction of a width 
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.frame.size.width = CGFloat(contentWidth)

}

}
```

Comment: This worked nicely. Now I'm trying to left justify the image and label against the left button bar. Should I be using constraints to do this? thx

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 + Interface Builder Solution**

As a follow-on to [Lyndsey Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274694/lyndsey-scott)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38548905/153081), you can also create a `UIView` .xib in Interface Builder, use that to lay out your title and image, and then update it on-the-fly via an `@IBOutlet`. This is useful for dynamic content, internationalization, maintainability etc.

[image: Interface Builder]

Create a `UIView` subclass with a `UILabel` outlet and assign your new .xib to this class:

```
import UIKit

class FolderTitleView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var title : UILabel!

    /// Create an instance of the class from its .xib
    class func instanceFromNib() -> FolderTitleView {
        return UINib(nibName: "FolderTitleView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! FolderTitleView
    }
}
```

Connect the label to your outlet (`title` in my example) in your .xib, then in your `UIViewController`:

```
/// Reference to the title view
var folderTitleView : FolderTitleView?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Set the screen title to match the active folder
    updateTitle()    
}

/// Updates the title of the navigation controller.
func updateTitle() {
    self.title = ""
    if folderTitleView == nil {
        folderTitleView = FolderTitleView.instanceFromNib()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = folderTitleView
    }
    folderTitleView!.title.text = "Listening"
    folderTitleView!.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This results in a nice self-centering title bar with an embedded image that you can easily update from code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

// worked for me

1. create a view and set the frame
2. now  add the image in the view and set the frame
3. after adding the image, add the label in same view and set the frame
4. after adding the image and label to view, add same view to navigationItem

   let  navigationView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  50 , height: 55))

   ```
   let labell : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -38, y: 25, width: 150, height: 25))
   labell.text = "Your text"
   labell.textColor = UIColor.black
   labell.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
   navigationView.addSubview(labell)

   let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: ValidationMessage.headerLogoName)!
   let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: -20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
   imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
   imageView.image = image
   //navigationItem.titleView = imageView

   navigationView.addSubview(imageView)

   navigationItem.titleView = navigationView
   ```