# iOS - add image and text to titleview with constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a custom title view for my nav bar with an image an some text next to it and this is how I did it thank to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47404105 :

```
class CustomTitleView: UIView
{

var title_label = CustomLabel()
var left_imageView = UIImageView()

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup(){
    self.addSubview(title_label)
    self.addSubview(left_imageView)

}

func loadWith(title: String, leftImage: UIImage?)
{
    title_label.text = title
    title_label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: FontManager.fontSize + 5)
    left_imageView.image = leftImage

    setupFrames()
}

func setupFrames()
{

    let height: CGFloat = 44
    let image_size: CGFloat = height * 0.8

    left_imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: (height - image_size) / 2,
                                  width: (left_imageView.image == nil) ? 0 : image_size,
                                  height: image_size)

    let titleWidth: CGFloat = title_label.intrinsicContentSize.width + 10
    title_label.frame = CGRect(x: left_imageView.frame.maxX + 5,
                               y: 0,
                               width: titleWidth,
                               height: height)



    contentWidth = Int(left_imageView.frame.width)
    self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(contentWidth), height: height)
}


var contentWidth: Int = 0 
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.frame.size.width = CGFloat(contentWidth)

}
```

But the problem is that I don't want to hardcode the frame, I want to use constraints but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Try to set view into storyboard and assign it to navigation title view. this is easiest and proper way

Comment: without assigning the constraint; does your navigation bar looks exactly as your code is written?

Comment: @vikramsingh yes it looks exactly how I want it to, but I want to do that with constraints.

Answer (score 0):

First take a `imageView` and set it's constraints according to your requirement and then take a `Label` besides that `imageView` set it's constraints too. Do this in your `navigationBar` where you want to show them.